# Django - ckeditor disappears after adding youtube plugin

Tags: python, django, plugins, youtube, ckeditor

I am trying to build a blog webpage  and also i want to share my youtube tutorials in my page so i need this plugin so much. when i add this plugin to my project, ckeditor disappears. Can somebody help me to fix this?

**models.py**

```
class Makale(models.Model):
kategori = models.ForeignKey(Kategori, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
# altKategori = models.ManyToManyField(AltKategori)
baslik = models.CharField(max_length=50)
kisaIcerik = models.TextField(max_length=300)
tamIcerik = RichTextField(external_plugin_resources = [(
    'youtube',
    '/static/ckeditor/ckeditor/plugins/youtube/',
    'plugin.js',
)])
```

**settings.py**

```
CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'default': {
        'toolbar': 'Custom',
        'toolbar_Custom' : [
            ['Bold', 'CodeSnippet', 'Font',
            'FontSize',
            'TextColor',
            'BGColor', 'NumberedList',
            'BulletedList',
            '-',
            'Outdent',
            'Indent',
            '-',
            'JustifyLeft',
            'JustifyCenter',
            'JustifyRight',
            'JustifyBlock',
            'Italic',
            'Underline',
            'Link',
            'Unlink',
            'RemoveFormat',
            'Source',
            'Image',
            'Youtube']
        ],
        'extraPlugins' : ','.join(['codesnippet', 'youtube']),
        'width': 'auto',
    },
}
```

when i remove youtube plugin from ckeditor_configs on settings.py it works perfect. The problem is on Youtube plugin. I don't know how to fix that.

Comment: Please, press F12 in your browser, go to the "console" tab and reload your page to see if you get any error messages we can help you with.

Comment: Thank you showing me a way to fix this. I've solved the problem by controlling the error messages in console. It works now.